# Is there a way to isolate an HTML element by class first and then id without a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, class, getelementbyid

I have a table with two columns of text. The rows in the left column have incrementing ids that belong to one class, and the other column has incrementing ids that all belong to another  class. These class/id definitions are done on the td level.

I need to find an element first by it's class, and then by it's id. I can get the class items by getItemsByClassName, and that gives me a node list. I think I can then iterate through that list and look for a matching id, but it seems a bit clunky with the manual for-loop/iteration. I need to do this quite frequently, so I was wondering if there was a better, more "supported" way to do this?

EDIT: Updated code sample

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td>
                <div class = "class1" id = "1"> Text </div>
           </td>
           <td>
                <div class = "class2" id = "1"> Text </div>
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

As the answer suggests below, it sounds like the problem could in fact be solved by actually making the ids unique.

Comment: Also, could you post the HTML?

Comment: Element ID's are supposed to be unique. Are yours not?

Comment: Why do you need to find the class first? You should only have unique ids, so you should just be able to go straight to each of them.

Comment: if you have the id already you do not need to iterate... not sure I understand your Q - post some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML, ids are supposed to be unique, only appearing once per document. If you are using IDs correctly, you should be able to get the element you need with `document.getElementById()` without regard to its class name.

If your IDs are not unique, then you need to fix that issue first.

Comment: It's a bit early to say OP has to change change things without knowing if that is actually the case or even if they have control over the HTML.

Comment: @lincolnk: Have you voted to close the question yet?

Comment: @Lizza: Because you hadn't edited your question yet, while people are saying it's too early to answer. But now that you've edited your question, nothing else needs to be done. (Had it not been edited sooner, it could easily be reopened as well after being closed.)

Comment: @Lizza Your best course of action may actually be to give your elements two classes (separate classes by a space). Classes don't need to be unique, and one element can have multiple classes.

Comment: @Paulpro thank you for that. I think that is exactly what I am going to do.